# Is there any way to give a base URL to different sub modules that are lazy loaded in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-module, base-url

I have a main angular application and in there there are different modules lazy loaded depending on the route

```
    {
        path: 'url1',
        pathMatch: 'prefix',
        loadChildren: './url1/url1.module#Module1'
    },
    {
        path: 'url1',
        pathMatch: 'prefix',
        loadChildren: './url1/url1.module#Module2'
    },
```

But inside the modules I have routerLinks in the htmls that navigates to different paths in the module selected but it does not consider the url1 or url2 as the base URL

I tried adding

```
 providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/url1' }
  ],
```

but for every URL, it does not append the url1 or url2 as base for every route link but it didnt work for me. how can I add the base url1 or url2 depending on the url when routing inside the modules like

so basically /subroute1/subroute2 should be as url1/subroute1/subroute2 since its giving an error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment /subroute1/subroute2

example routing for sub modules

```
   { 
        path: '',
        component: Module1MainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your router links do not start with `/` instead:
[If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)

Comment: can you share your routing for 'Module1' and 'Module2' ?

Comment: @Yogendra123 I have updated with the sub module routing

Answer (score 0):

Update your base module route

```
  {
    path: 'url1',
    loadChildren: './url1/url1.module#Module1'
  },
  {
    path: 'url2',
    loadChildren: './url2/url2.module#Module2'
  },
```

You can remove pathMatch, Your sub module routes look fine,

Make sure in the main module call `forRoot` and in the sub modules call `forChild` of the `RouterModule` like:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

You don't need `APP_BASE_HREF`

lets say you want to redirect from ur1/subroute1 to url2/subroute2, then, your routerlink will look like this:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['../url1/subroute2']">Go to</a>
```